# How do I write code for k fold cross validation in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I am new to machine learning and I am working with a small dataset to train a CNN. I already tried data augmentation but it wont get past 75% accuracy. I was wondering k fold cross validation might be the next course of action. However I do not know how to write code for it.

Here is my code so far:

**The data directories:**

```
train_dir = '../input/train_images'
train_labels = pd.read_csv('../input/train.csv')
train_labels['diagnosis'] = train_labels['diagnosis'].astype(str)
train_labels["id_code"]=train_labels["id_code"].apply(lambda x:x+".png")


test_dir = '../input/test_images'
test_labels = '../input/test.csv'
```

**Preprocessing:**

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_labels, 
    directory= train_dir,
    x_col='id_code', y_col='diagnosis', 
    target_size=(150, 150), 
    color_mode='grayscale', 
    class_mode='categorical', 
    batch_size=32, 
    shuffle=True,)
```

**The model:**

```
def get_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150,150,3)))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))

    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

    #Compile your model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer=optimizers.Adam(),
                metrics=['acc'])

    return model
```

The dataset can be found in the following link:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/aptos2019-blindness-detection/data